# Installing XCode command line tools fails

Tags: xcode, macos, dyld

I'm trying to install the command line tools on Yosemite but I'm getting the following error:

```
$ xcode-select --install

dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_png_create_info_struct
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
  Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libPng.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

What is causing this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: Do you have `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable set?

Comment: No, but there is a file at /usr/local/lib/libPng.dylib.

Comment: Your problem is that user installed `libpng` overshadows system one. You could uninstall it, but then some non-system executables may complain.

Comment: I think `matplotlib` is the reason there's a new user installed `libpng`. Is there some way I can check what version of `libpng` I installed and what version is expected by XCode?

Comment: I take that back about `matplotlib`. The version of `libpng` I have was installed through `homebrew`, but I installed `matplotlib` through `pip`.

Comment: Is `/usr/local/lib/libPng.dylib` a symlink or a regular file?

Comment: It's a symlink to the `libPng` in `/usr/local/Cellar` that homebrew installs.